Range and domain of composite function
We have the domain and target set of functions $f(x)=5x-3$ and $g(x)=x^2$ are $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $h(x)=f \circ g (x)$.
The question is what is the domain, target and range of $h(x)$?
I do not know the range of $h(x)$ is $[-3,+\infty)$ or $\{y \in \mathbb{Z}| \exists x\in \mathbb{Z}, h(x)=y \}$

Domain: $\mathbb{Z}$ (this should be obvious by definition of function composition).
Target: $\mathbb{Z}$ (this should also be obvious by the definition of function composition).
Range: The range is the possible values of the output of the function for all values in the domain. We have thus that:
$f\circ g\,(x)=5x^2-3.$ Thus, the range of $f \circ g$ is $\{5x^2-3:x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.
The statement $[-3,\infty)$ is the range would be incorrect,as this would suggest for example you could have $-2.5$ as a possible output to the function (which we know is nonsensical, as the output should be an integer).

For $f\circ g(x)$ to exist we need the range of $g$ to be a proper subset of the domain of $f$.
If this does not happen, we need to restrict the domain of $g$ to make it happen.
In this case, thankfully, the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the range of $g$ is the set of "squares" ($n^2$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$). Since this is a proper subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, the composition works with no restrictions needed.
Since no restrictions are needed, the domain of $f\circ g(x)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.
There are no fractions, radicals or other functions that would take integers and produce non-integers here so the Target will also be $\mathbb{Z}$
The range is then found by substitution: $h(0)=-3, h(1)=h(-1)=2, h(2)=h(-2)=17,...$
This can be written as $\{5n^2-3:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

The domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, as is the codomain (target) of $g$.  However, the range of $g$ only includes the perfect squares in $\mathbb{Z}$, not the entire set of integers.

Yes, of course. I should have been more specific there. Editing now. Thanks.

At the expense of sounding a little harsh, this answer is a bit ambiguous. The statement "the range of  g has to be a "proper" subset of the domain of f" is not correct generally. I.e define the function $g:${1}$\rightarrow$ {1}$, g(1)=1$, then you can compose g with itself: i.e there is no need for the range of g to be a "proper" subset of the domain of g.  The reasoning why the target is $\mathbb{Z}$ is also not correct, you should refer to the definition presented here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition.  It is not because only integers will be produced under $f \circ g$

As a furthering to my final statement: I could take the function g:$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ : $g(x)=1$. You would not claim that the target of this function is $\mathbb{Z}$ or {1} for example, even though the outputs are clearly all integers, the target is $\mathbb{R}$

Actually a very helpful comment. Thanks @JD
